# Prove that $\frac{1}{n + 1}{2n\choose n}$ is a positive integer for $n \ge 0$.

Tags: combinatorics

I attempted to use Pascal's triangle identity to help out, but I do not know how to deal with $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: look up the Catalan numbers

Answer (score 10):

The combinatorial approach is to notice that $\frac1{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), so it's an integer because it counts something.

Algebraically, one possible approach is to notice that
$$
   \frac1{n+1} \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!\,(n+1)!} = \frac1{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{n}.
$$
From the left expression, we know the denominator of the fraction is a divisor of $n+1$. From the right expression, we know the denominator is a divisor of $2n+1$.

But the only positive integer that's a divisor of *both* $n+1$ and $2n+1$ is $1$: one way to see this is that a divisor of $n+1$ and $2n+1$ is a divisor of $2(n+1)-1(2n+1) = 1$. So the denominator can only be $1$; the fraction is an integer.

Comment: I’m sorry.  I just can’t see what you’re doing after “But gcd...”.  Are you able to rephrase?

Comment: Rephrased. Does this help?

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1:**

Note that
$$
\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\overbrace{\ \ \binom{2n}{n}\ \ }^{\large\frac{(2n)!}{n!\,n!}}=\overbrace{\binom{2n+1}{n+1}}^{\large\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n+1)!\,n!}}
$$
Then, because $\frac1{n+1}=2-\frac{2n+1}{n+1}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}
&=2\binom{2n}{n}-\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\\
&=2\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n+1}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Approach 2:**

Note that
$$
\frac{n}{n+1}\overbrace{\ \ \binom{2n}{n}\ \ }^{\large\frac{(2n)!}{n!\,n!}}=\overbrace{\binom{2n}{n+1}}^{\large\frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)!\,(n-1)!}}
$$
Then, because $\frac1{n+1}=1-\frac{n}{n+1}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}
&=\binom{2n}{n}-\frac{n}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\\
&=\binom{2n}{n}-\binom{2n}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I don’t understand how this is done.  Are you able to add a little more detail in your steps?

Comment: @user524037: not sure what was unclear, so I added more detail to everything.

Comment: Is there something wrong? A second approach is added and it gets a downvote.